# Fullcalendar agregar una columna personalizada

Tags: bootstrap, fullcalendar

Estoy usando fullcalendar para un proyecto con calendarios.  Necesito agregar una columna personalizada con titulo "Semana", de esta forma:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No he logrado encontrar información que solucione mi problema.

```
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      headerToolbar: {
        left: '',
        center: 'title',
        right: ''
      },
      locales: 'es',
      header : {
      left:   'title',
      center: '',
      right: ''
      },
      dayHeaderFormat: { weekday: 'long' },  
      initialDate: today,
      events: [
          {
          daysOfWeek: [0,6], //Sundays and saturdays
          overlap: false,
          display: 'background', 
          color: "#ECEC92"
        },
        {
          daysOfWeek: [1,2,3,4,5], 
          overlap: false,
          display: 'background', 
          color: "#E1E1E1"
        },
        {
          title: '18/03/2022',
          start: '2022-03-18',
          color: 'black',
          align: 'center'
        },
      ],
    });

    calendar.render();
  });
```

Comment: Muestra tu código, para ver que has hecho y para que te podamos ayudar

Comment: @2coolDevs agregado

Comment: acabo de implementar un fullcalendar, en este caso me muestra tres botones: Mes, Semana y Dia, por default aparece resaltado el de Mes y te muestra todos los dias correspondientes al mes , si haces clic en Semana , te muestra solo la semana correspondiente y si haces clic en Día , solo te muestra los eventos del día.   No sé si es lo que estas buscando llevar a cabo.  Volvi a leer tu comentario. ya vi que intentas añadir una columna adicional con el titulo semana.  Creo que necesitas checar el sitio de fullcalendar haber si te permite esta opción

Comment: @Cesarin necesito que la columna semana esté fija.

Comment: Yo tuve que modificar un poco el archivo es.js del fullcalendar del ejemplo que tome como base para mi calendario,  quizás desde ahí puedas añadir la palabra semana, la otra es buscar el archivo js que esta relacionado con la semana y modificar ahí, pero no se que cantidad de errores te pueda mandar, ya que esta muy estructurado el código y cualquier cambio puede generar errores.  Por no dejar te pongo a liga del sitio fullcalendar https://fullcalendar.io/

Comment: @Cesarin gracias por la ayuda, también estoy intentando hacer un append a la tabla con jquery, pero no funciona.

Comment: revisa esta linea : /* Date Utilities
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
var dayIDs = [ 'sun', 'mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat' ];  // Linea 634 en el archivo de fullcalendar.js  quizás encuentres la forma de alterar el contenido del calendario desde los js desde los mismos archivos del proyecto fullcalendar... tienes tarea para rato.  Saludos P.D. un proyecto que a lo mejor te es útil: https://github.com/icodeart/Calendario-Bootstrap-php-mysql

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [jquery agregar columnas y filas a tabla existente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/523156/jquery-agregar-columnas-y-filas-a-tabla-existente)