# jquery agregar columnas y filas a tabla existente

Tags: html, jquery

Quiero agregar columnas con borde para el resto de las semanas a la derecha de la tabla(es una tabla fullcalendar), intenté con este código pero no funciona bien:

```
    $("table tr:first").append("<td style='width:80px'>Semana</td>");
    $("table tr:gt(0)").append("<td>Col</td>");
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podría lograr agregar la columna y filas a la tabla ya existente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He tenido que analizar concretamente la estructura de la tabla de fullcalendar y algo he conseguido mirando y copiando las clases que he encontrado en uno de sus ejemplos, pero esa es la idea.

He tenido que deshabilitar cualquier tipo de cambio de vista, es decir, tan solo se muestra el fullcalendar entre un rango predeterminado de fechas, la cual en este ejemplo he establecido en un mes. De otro modo, si se pulsaba cualquier botón para cambiar la vista, se renderizaba mal.  Se que es una solución a medias, pero tambien creo que el OP puede al menos jugar con eso de algún modo para que externamente vaya llamando a otros meses repitiendo este código y cambiando el rango de fechas.

Prueba con algo como esto:

```js
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('fullcalendar1')
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
  initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
  validRange: {
    start: '2022-03-01',
    end: '2022-03-31'
  },
  headerToolbar: {
    left: '',
    center: 'title',
    right: ''
  },
  fixedWeekCount: false,
});
calendar.render();


i = 0
var testcolumn = `<td role="gridcell" class="fc-daygrid-day fc-day fc-day-past fc-day-other" data-date="" aria-labelledby="fc-dom-2"><div class="fc-daygrid-day-frame fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner"><div class="fc-daygrid-day-top"><a id="" class="fc-daygrid-day-number" aria-label="">Aquí</a></div><div class="fc-daygrid-day-events"><div class="fc-daygrid-day-bottom" style="margin-top: 0px;">texto aqui</div></div><div class="fc-daygrid-day-bg"></div></div></td>`
var testheader = `<th role="columnheader" class="fc-col-header-cell fc-day fc-day-sat"><div class="fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner"><a aria-label="Saturday" class="fc-col-header-cell-cushion ">Semana</a></div></th>`
$("tr[role^='row']").each(function() {
  if (i == 0) {
    this.innerHTML += testheader
  } else {
    this.innerHTML += testcolumn
  }
  i++
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.10.2/main.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.10.2/main.min.js'></script>

<div id="fullcalendar1">

</div>
```

### Explicación

Con la función [each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) de jquery recorres todas las filas (**tr[role^='row']**) de la tabla que cumplen la condición de contener el atributo `role="row"`, que es el que usa fullcalendar segun parece. A las cuales le pasas una función que comprueba, mediante un condicional, si es la primera, en cuyo caso agrega la columna con el texto `Semana` en formato HTML (**innerHTML**), y en las siguientes le agrega un texto (aquí es donde ya entra el OP a modificarlo como le convenga en cada ciclo).

Comment: no es el número de la semana lo que busco, si no el monto acumulado en la semana.  Probé el código y muestra los datos amontonados, es una tabla de fullcalendar.

Comment: ¿Que quieres decir con amontonados?  ¿Pegadas las cantidades a sumar?  Pon el código en alguna parte de lo que has hecho para poderlo ver.  Si estan pegados es porque son strings y no números. O pon un enlace a la imagen para que vea lo que tu ves

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/lLALn4s.png

Comment: vale, eso no es bueno... quita mi código, no te va a servir para fullcalendar entonces, tan solo para tablas "normales"... a saber la estructura de la tabla de fullcalendar como es, seguro que es un poco liosa

Comment: Actualiza la página y mira mi respuesta de nuevo.  Ahora sale algo mejor el tema. He tenido que mirar y copiar las clases que he encontrado en uno de sus ejemplos, pero esa es la idea.

Comment: duplica los días de la semana https://i.imgur.com/KcBUIri.png

Comment: Eso es que no te has leido mi explicación detenidamente. No tengo solución a eso. Si ejecutas el snippet de la respuesta veras que no lo hace aqui (pero no te deja mover ni adelante ni atras, solo el mes que tenga puesto como rango).

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134977/discussion-between-user2820116-and-masterguru).